# How to copy a node xml and appended to the specified node using linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an xml,like this :

```
<advReqData>
  <sessionid></sessionid>
  <akc190></akc190>
  <meds>
    <med>
      <idx></idx>
      <alc400></alc400>
    </med>
  </meds>
</advReqData>
```

I would like to using **linq to xml** make XML into the following structure:

```
<advReqData>
  <sessionid></sessionid>
  <akc190></akc190>
  <meds>
    <med>
      <idx></idx>
      <alc400></alc400>
    </med>
    <med>
      <idx></idx>
      <alc400></alc400>
    </med>
  </meds>
</advReqData>
```

That is, in the meds node under the addition of a new med node, the new med node and the original document med node structure is the same.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the first element in "meds" and then add it to the end

```
var fn = xelement.Element("meds").FirstNode;
xelement.Element("meds").Add(fn);
```